# v-tabs content overflows but show arrows doesnot work

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetify-tabs

I have this code

```
<v-toolbar>
  <v-tabs
        next-icon="mdi-arrow-right"
        prev-icon="mdi-arrow-left"
        show-arrows="always"
        hide-slider
        icons-and-text
        centered
      >
        <v-tab>
          Button 1 
        </v-tab>

         <v-tab>
          Button 2
        </v-tab>

        <v-divider>

         <v-tab>
          Button 3
        </v-tab>

         ....
         <v-tab>
          Button n
        </v-tab>
```

the issue is that although the number of button exceeds the maximum width (overflows) but show arrows is still disabled . I have to click some button then it becomes enable. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

Is the content inside the buttons load after some time thus causing it to overflow? the fact that after you click somewhere it works, probably means they are doing a calculation before but not after, if it is the fact, try changing some props for the v-tabs once your content has rendered and causing an overflow